# Change bottom bar container color of react navigation tabs in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to add border radius to bottom bar but with this 
i want to change container color from default to purple.

how can i do that  ?

**What i have done so far**

[image]

**What i want**

[image]

Code:

```
tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.primary,
      inactiveTintColor: colors.black,
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
        borderTopRightRadius: 20,
        borderColor: colors.lightGrayText,
      },
    },
```

Anyone can help ?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add a position absolute which will make the tabbar stay inside the border

```
tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: 'red',
          inactiveTintColor: 'black',
          showLabel: false,
          style: {
            borderWidth: 0.5,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
            borderTopRightRadius: 20,
            borderColor: 'grey',
            position: 'absolute'
          },
        }}>
```

Reference 
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5928

Answer (score 1):

If you have nested bottom tab into stack you should change color in stack screen , like code bellow

```
<Stack.Screen
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
      cardStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
      },
    }}
    name={mainStack.homeTab}
    component={HomeTabs}
  />
```